# Como configurar para que os testes com controllers utilizem requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Após criar uma controller um teste para a controller é automaticamente criado. É possível desabilitar essa criação do teste para a controller utilizando o código abaixo:

```
Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec, controller_specs: false
end
```

Feito isso, o normal seria criar o request manualmente. Outra ideia para solucionar seria sobrescrever o gerador da controller.

Bom, gostaria de saber se existe algum tipo de configuração que possa habilitar o uso de criação de testes para requestes ao invés de testes para controllers.